# Solving this 2nd order linear ODE with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following 2nd order differential equation:

$x y''(x) + (x + a) y' (x) + b y(x) = 0 $

I post it because it looks quite simple and I'm pretty sure someone knows a way to handle those kinds of equations (polynomial solution don't work)

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What looks interesting is the case where $b=a+n$, $n$ being an integer. I

Comment: why would that look interesting? your comment is interesting to me :-) because given 2 Dirichlet conditions I'd like to put constraints on $a$, $b$ such that maybe $a$ can take any value but $b$ must be in a countable set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very similar equation is the confluent hypergeometric equation. 
$$ z f''(z) +(b-z)f'(z) -af(z)=0$$
It has two (generally) linearly independent solutions $M(a,b,z)$ and $U(a,b,z)$, known respectively as Kummer's and Tricomi's functions.
$$f(z)=C_1 M(a,b,z)+C_2U(a,b,z)$$
In order to transform your equation into this one, apply the substitution $z=-x$, so that:
$$f(z)=y(-z)=y(x)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}y(x)= \frac{dz}{dx}\frac{d}{dz}f(z)=-f'(z)$$
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y(x)=f''(z)$$
Your equation then becomes:
$$-zf''(z)+(-z+a)(-f'(z))+bf(z)=0$$
and ultimately:
$$zf''(z)+(a-z)f'(z)-bf(z)=0$$
whose solution is given by the functions above.
For any reference to this kind of equation I suggest you to have a look at *Handbook of mathematical functions*, by Abramowitz and Stegun.

Answer (score 2):

In the same spirit as NSZ's answer, start defining $y=z\,e^{-x}$ to get $$x z''+(a-x) z'+(b-a)z=0$$ the solution of which being $$z=c_1\, U(a-b,a,x)+c_2 \,L_{b-a}^{a-1}(x)$$ where appear  the confluent hypergeometric function and [the generalized Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! I must use boundary conditions to put constraints on the $a$ and $b$ parameters, I'll try to figure out the best formulation between your 2 alternatives to do so

Comment: @ClementRoussel. the answers are basically the same (look at the relations given in the Wikipedia page between generalized Laguerre polynomials  and confluent hypergeometric functions). As I commented, there would be amazing things to do for $b=a+n$. Cheers.

Comment: you stay mysterious with the "amazing things to do" :-) you were really helpful though, thank you

Comment: @ClementRoussel. *Pas de mystère !* In such cases, we end with quite simple polynomials. Look at the recurrence relation for $\,L_{n}^{a-1}(x)$. By the ways, what kind of boundary conditions do you need to handle ? Cheers. By the way, you are very welcome.

Comment: ^^ to be fully transparent my $b$ coefficient is actually $b+\lambda$. I'm facing an eigenvalue problem. Using Dirichlet boundary conditions or Robin boundary conditions, I'd like to end up seeing that $\lambda$ can take only discrete values, i.e. belongs to a countable set $\{\lambda _n, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. I have 2 boundaries: $x_{min}, x_{max}$ and my conditions are simply (if I choose the Dirichlet BC) $z(x_{min}) = z(x_{max}) = 0$

Comment: @ClementRoussel. Thanks for "clarifying" ! Now, I am lost ! May I confess that I am not a mathematician ? Good luck.

Comment: ahah are there such things as mathematicians and non-mathematicians? :-)